# listview with checkbox mono for android

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, xamarin.android

I have a problem with checkboxes in listview.

Every raw have it's own checkbox and textview.

If i check 1st checkbox -> checked become every 5th checkbox (2-nd -> 6th)

Where is the problem?

Comment: please post some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Without some posted code it's impossible to say for sure but it sounds like an issue with View  recycling in your List Adapter. If you are maintaining references to specific Views in your Activity you will have problems when the view is recycled because your reference will now point to a different view.